# I am not able to redirect page on noscript

Tags: php, javascript, html

I want that if the javascript of browser is turned off, user should be redirected to a new page...

I tried doing this way but not working... `<noscript><?php header("location: js-error.php"); ?></noscript>`

This script is redirecting page to js-error.php even if javascript is ON.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Headers already sent by PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/headers-already-sent-by-php)

Comment: You mix two tehnologies. You didn't read what and how do header() function

Answer (score 5):

This does not work because you cannot set [`header()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)s after output has been sent.

> Remember that header() must be called before any actual output is
>   sent, either by normal HTML tags, blank lines in a file, or from PHP.

The way to do this would be with a [`meta-refresh`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh) although some browsers may not honour this directive. For example:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://example.org">
```

My preferred methodology is not to redirect at all but show a simple modal (with straight CSS)  telling them how to enable JavaScript. There is an example on [Let me have a blog](http://letmehaveblog.blogspot.co.uk/2007/08/correct-way-for-javascript-detection.html) of the type of message I am advocating.

Comment: In addition to meta-refresh you could also just display some html between those tags while waiting for the page to refresh (or instead if you are just displaying an error)

Answer (score 3):

Alternate way:

```
<noscript>
<!--
    meta-tag "refresh" is provided for those browsers that
    do not support JavaScript.  Please note that the time
    delay is greater than zero.

    Notice that this is nested within a "noscript" block.
    Which means that browsers that support JavaScript will
    not "see" the refresh meta-tag.
-->
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2; URL=redirectiontarget.htm">
</noscript>
```

http://grizzlyweb.com/webmaster/javascripts/redirection.asp

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing two technologies together. The php call, redirects you from the server side, even before the page is fully rendered for sending to the client.